# Adaptive Cards in MS Teams - Header and Notification

Tags: microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

I am sending an adaptive card to a Microsoft Teams chat using the Graph API. I have been following [this in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/graph/api/chatmessage-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#example-3-send-message-containing-cards), but I've changed `application/vnd.microsoft.card.thumbnail` to `application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive` in my code, and am using a card I designed using https://adaptivecards.io.

I have a couple of questions:

1. When I post a message with an adaptive card, it looks like its inside another container rather than the whole message just being the card. Where does this header come from? Can I customize it or remove it?
   [image: Adaptive card in a Teams chat. The card appears to be inside another container that has a thumbnail.]
2. When I send an HTML message, the content of the message shows up in the toast notification. Can I set preview or notification content in a card?

**Edit:** here is the code for the adaptive card (note that I replace `{VisitorNam}` and `{VisitorEmail}` in my code before sending this):

```json
{
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "backgroundImage": {
        "url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/matt-goldman/matt-goldman/main/assets/synth.jpg",
        "fillMode": "Cover",
        "verticalAlignment": "Center",
        "horizontalAlignment": "Center"
    },
    "minHeight": "200px",
    "body": [
        {
            "type": "ColumnSet",
            "columns": [
                {
                    "type": "Column",
                    "width": "stretch",
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "type": "TextBlock",
                            "text": "G'day, you have a visitor!",
                            "wrap": true,
                            "size": "ExtraLarge",
                            "color": "Light",
                            "weight": "Bolder"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "type": "Column",
                    "width": "auto",
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "type": "Image",
                            "horizontalAlignment": "Right",
                            "url": "https://github.com/matt-goldman/matt-goldman/raw/main/assets/synth_logo_thumb.png"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": "**{visitorName}**",
            "wrap": true,
            "color": "Light",
            "size": "ExtraLarge"
        },
        {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": "\n({visitorEmail})\nis here to see you and is waiting in the lobby.",
            "wrap": true,
            "color": "Light",
            "size": "Large"
        }
    ],
    "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
    "version": "1.4"
}
```

**Edit 2:** Here is the method where I am sending this using the Graph SDK for .NET. The `GenerateCardContent` method returns the JSON listed above, but with the substitutions made.

```cs
public async Task SendNotification(string staffId, string visitorName, string visitorEmail)
    {
        
        try
        {
            var chat = new Chat
            {
                ChatType = ChatType.OneOnOne,
                Members = new List<ConversationMember>
                {
                    new ConversationMember
                    {
                        OdataType = "#microsoft.graph.aadUserConversationMember",
                        Roles = new List<string>
                        {
                            "owner",
                        },
                        AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>
                        {
                            {
                                "user@odata.bind" , $"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users('{_options.TeamsSenderId}')"
                            },
                        },
                    },
                    new ConversationMember
                    {
                        OdataType = "#microsoft.graph.aadUserConversationMember",
                        Roles = new List<string>
                        {
                            "owner",
                        },
                        AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>
                        {
                            {
                                "user@odata.bind" , $"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users('{staffId}')"
                            },
                        },
                    },
                }
            };

            var teamsChat = await _graphClient.Chats.PostAsync(chat);

            var attachmentGuid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

            var message = new ChatMessage
            {
                Body = new ItemBody
                {
                    Content = $"<attachment id=\"{attachmentGuid}\"></attachment>",
                    ContentType = BodyType.Html,
                },
                Importance = ChatMessageImportance.Normal,
                MessageType = ChatMessageType.Message,
                Locale = "en/AU",
                Attachments = new List<ChatMessageAttachment>
                {
                    new ChatMessageAttachment
                    {
                        Id = attachmentGuid,
                        ContentType = "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
                        ContentUrl = null,
                        Content = GenerateCardContent(visitorName, visitorEmail),
                        Name = null,
                        ThumbnailUrl = null,
                    },
                }
            };

            var msg = await _teamsSenderClient.Chats[teamsChat.Id].Messages.PostAsync(message);

            Console.WriteLine($"[GraphService] Sent message: {msg.Id}");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError("Error sending visitor notification", ex);
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Comment: We did try sending both thumbnail card and adaptive card using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chatmessage-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-3-send-message-containing-cards. [Thumbnail card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3uQFs.png) and [adaptive card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3WAN.png). We do not see any extra header, could you please share your adaptive card JSON with us?

Comment: @Meghana-MSFT done - I've updated the question to include the adaptive card json

Comment: One question at a time, please. [ask]

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site.

Comment: I don't think this is at all helpful Rob. For someone that actually has any knowledge of the topic, the information in the question is sufficient. If you believe blind adherence to the rules without further context is the way to go, then awesome, great job 

Comment: @MattG - 1. Are you setting [teamsAppId](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chatmessage-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#example-9-send-message-that-contains-cards-that-are-attributed-to-a-teams-app) in the request body? That header should have the app details if the teamsAppID is set.
2. No, you can use feed APIs for this.

Comment: @Meghana-MSFT I'm not using the teamsAppId as I'm not sending it as a Teams App, just sending it to a chat using the Graph SDK. I've updated the question to include the code I'm using to send it.

Comment: @MattG - Apologies for the delay. Engineering team has confirmed that the above card is expected. Cards sent from Graph will now have a default placeholder for app icon.  To modify it you can set [teamsAppID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chatmessage-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#example-9-send-message-that-contains-cards-that-are-attributed-to-a-teams-app) to show the app details, but please note that it cannot be removed. https://i.stack.imgur.com/7iSmY.png

Comment: Thanks @Meghana-MSFT. Can you post that as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Engineering team has confirmed that the above card is expected. Cards sent from Graph will now have a default placeholder for app icon. To modify it you can set [teamsAppID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chatmessage-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#request-8) to show the app details, but please note that it cannot be removed. [image]
2. No, you can use feed APIs for this.